# Why is 3log8(n) the dominant term in 3log8(n) + log2log2log2n?

Tags: math, big-o, computer-science

Why is `3log8(n)` the dominant term in `3log8(n) + log2log2log2(n)`?

I thought it was `log2log2log2(n)` since it is larger is it not?

Comment: What does `log2log2log2(n)` mean?

Comment: `3 * log (n, 8) = 3 * log(n, 2) / log(8, 2) = log(n, 2)`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you should ask it on math.stackexchange.com, rather than here.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that

```
 log2log2log2(n) == log(log(log(n, 2), 2), 2)
 
 3log8(n)        == 3 * log(n, 8)
```

we can compute *limit* to compare asymptotics:

```
 lim log(log(log(n, 2), 2), 2) / (3 * log(n, 8))
 n -> inf
```

since

```
 3 * log(n, 8) = 3 * log(n, 2) / log(8, 2) = log(n, 2)
```

the limit is

```
 lim log(log(log(n, 2), 2), 2) / log(n, 2) =
 n -> inf
```

Let's use [l'Hôpital's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) rule:

```
 = lim const * n / (n * log(n, 2) * log(log(n, 2), 2)) =
   n -> inf  

 = lim const / (log(n, 2) * log(log(n, 2), 2)) =
   n -> inf

 = 0
```

Since *limit* is **0** `3 * log(n, 8)` grows faster then `log(log(log(n, 2), 2), 2)`, i.e.
`3 * log(n, 8)` *dominates*

Answer (score 0):

No, log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>2</sub>(*n*))) grows much more slowly than log<sub>2</sub>(*n*) as *n* gets larger.

As dmitry noted, 3log<sub>8</sub>(*n*) = log<sub>2</sub>(*n*)